# Getting value from FormControl with inputRef results in Unknown prop `inputRef` on <input>

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap

I started with some simple redux-react application but now I would like to play a bit with the react-bootstrap package. But I can't find the good way to get the value.

First, i had something like this

```
<input  ref={input => client.name = input} ..../>
```

But from the stuff, i found here https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2418. I would simply need to replace this with `inputRef`.

So I tried the example but I get following exception in the console.

> Unknown prop `inputRef` on `<input>`

Any idea how I can get this working? And what is the preferable redux way for this scenario?

```
export default class Test extends Component {

    render() {


        const {client} = this.props;
            return (
                <div>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <InputGroup>
                            <FormControl inputRef={input => client.name = input} type="text"/>
                        </InputGroup>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <button onClick={() => {
                        {
                            console.log(client.name.value)
                        }
                    }
                    } role="button" className="btn btn-primary">test
                    </button>
                </div>
            )
    }
```

Comment: try to include second `{}` as the arrow function body: `<FormControl inputRef={input => {client.name = input;}} type="text"/>`

Comment: Same problem here, and the second pair of curly brackets does nothing for it.

Comment: @JulienD I solved it by replacing  FormControl with <input .... ref={input => this.itemName = input} But I could not get the input from the FormControl